# Intellisense slows down my computer

Tags: visual-studio-2013, intellisense

I'm testing the Visual Studio 2013. The intellisense is awesome and helps you a lot, but I'm noticing it slows down a lot my computer. When I write in the IDE, it goes like slow...

Is any option to just show the autocomplete when I press a hotkey? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Modifying IntelliSense Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ecfczya1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). You want "Tools"->"Options"->"Text Editor"->(choose language or All Languages)->uncheck "Auto list members". You can still get statement completion with `ctrl-j`.

You may also want to read [Productivity Tips for Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj153218.aspx).

[The downvotes might be due to people not realizing that asking about software tools commonly used by programmers is in scope for this forum: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).]